# Using a function to query a database

Tags: php

I have a page and I would really like some help / advice to create a better way / function to call in information from another table.

At the moment, my code looks like:
[I do know this is deprecated SQL and would really like to do some nice SQLi for this.]

```
<?
$menuid = "100";
$imageid = "50";

// ** Talk to 'imagedirectory' table

mysql_select_db($database_db, $BASEdb);
$query_displayimage = "SELECT * FROM imagedirectory WHERE menuid = ".$menuid." AND imageid = ".$imageid."";
$displayimage = mysql_query($query_displayimage, $BASEdb) or die(mysql_error());
$row_displayimage= mysql_fetch_assoc($displayimage);

?>

<img src="/images/assets/<?php echo $menuid; ?>-<?php echo $imageid; ?>-<?php echo $row_displayimage['urlslug']; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row_displayimage['alttext']; ?>" />
```

I figure There really has to be a better way because if there is 10 images on a page, this is pretty intense way of doing it.

Comment: What do you intend to gain from this question? When you already know that mysql_*() functions are deprecated and using MySQLi is the way to go, you got everything you need to educate yourself. For example here: http://php.net/mysqli

Comment: hi @icefyre - I appreciate your comments, I am sure I will be to  Google and replicate the above code in SQLi without too much trouble I'd imagine. The thing I don't want to do is actually replicate that code. There has to be a better way to do this via a function of some sort, though I don't really know where to begin. What I am after is some help with the logic.

Comment: I understand. However, you only provided a code without any information about the logic. What is the purpose of your script?

Comment: I might adjust my question a little to be more specific. Though in essence I go through the above code to get the 'urlslug' and 'alttext' fields from a 'imagedirectory' table to display an image. The problem is that if I have 10 images on a page I literally have to repeat the above code 10x, I would like to have it so I have a function where I can easily tell the request the 'menuid' and 'imageid' and it spits out a result: <img src="/images/assets/ $menuid-$imageid-$urlslug.jpg" alt="$alttext" />

Comment: Apologies on the lack of detail/direction of my question.

Comment: Just select all images (without a `where` condition) and do a loop. If you need the images on different places (e.g. half at the beginning and the other half at the end), you could store them in an array. Read more about the function here: http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to know that `mysql_*` is deprecated, I am assuming you have read up on, and are using `mysqli_*` instead.

You needn't query the database every time. `mysqli_query()` returns a `mysqli_result`, which you can iterate over, and read using functions like `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. Here is one way of doing it:

```
<?php

// store your query in a variable.
$query_displayimage = "SELECT * FROM imagedirectory";

// query the database.
$displayimage = mysqli_query($query_displayimage, $BASEdb);

// check for errors.
$dbErrors = mysqli_error($BASEdb);
if (count($dbErrors))
{
    print_r($dbErrors);
    die();
}

// iterate over the returned resource.
while ($row_displayimage = mysql_fetch_assoc($displayimage))
{
    echo '<img src="/images/assets/' . $menuid . '-' . $imageid . '-' . $row_displayimage['urlslug'] . '.jpg" alt="' . $row_displayimage['alttext'] . '" />';
}

?>
```

Hope that helped.

---

#### EDIT:

You can use this code in a function, too. For example:

```
<?php

function printImage($menuid, $imageid)
{
    $query_displayimage = "SELECT * FROM imagedirectory";
    $displayimage = mysqli_query($query_displayimage, $BASEdb);
    $dbErrors = mysqli_error($BASEdb);
    if (count($dbErrors))
    {
        print_r($dbErrors);
        die();
    }
    
    if ($row_displayimage = mysql_fetch_assoc($displayimage))
    {
        echo '<img src="/images/assets/' . $menuid . '-' . $imageid . '-' . $row_displayimage['urlslug'] . '.jpg" alt="' . $row_displayimage['alttext'] . '" />';
    }
    else    // if there is a problem getting the image
    {
        echo 'Error getting image.';
    }
}

?>
```

and elsewhere in your HTML, you would do something like:

```
<div>
    And here is an image!
    <?php printImage(20, 50); ?>
</div>
```